# How to UnProtect Sheet using OpenXML code?

Tags: openxml

I have created one Sheet, which i could protect using OpenXml code.

But now there is requirement to read this excel file.

I am getting all the values as NULL because it is protected.

( I haven't placed any password yet in the code to protect the sheet, there is only one sheet in the excel file.)

I have got below code from my Search to unprotect the worksheet.

```
  workSheet.RemoveAllChildren<SheetProtection>();
```

But, this is not working. I am still getting the null values while reading this protected sheet.

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FilePath, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
                //if ((sheets.Count() != 2) && (sheets.First().Name.Value != "StudentNomination") && (sheets.Last().Name.Value != "Sheet2"))
                //{
                //    throw new Exception("Please Upload the correct Nomination file, for example you can download the Nomination Template file first.!!");
                //}
                string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
                Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
                workSheet.RemoveAllChildren<SheetProtection>();
                SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();
```

Can anyone Please help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code for removing protection is correct. But before that you have to open the Excel file in Edit Mode. The second argument in `SpreadSheetDocument.Open` should be set to `true`.

Also Regardless of protection, you should be able to read a cell's value. See the below code. In order to test this you would have to create a excel file and fill the cells A1,B1 and C1 with numbers.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

class Test
{

    static void Main()
    {
        string filePath = @"E:\test.xlsx";
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

            var dataBeforeProtection = workSheet.Descendants<Row>().First().Descendants<Cell>().First().CellValue.InnerText;
            workSheet.RemoveAllChildren<SheetProtection>();
            var dataAfterProtection = workSheet.Descendants<Row>().First().Descendants<Cell>().First().CellValue.InnerText;
            workSheet.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello CVRaman, Thank you for your response. I have tried your code to open the excel file in Edit mode, but it gives me below exception.ex = {"Cannot open package because FileMode or FileAccess value is not valid for the stream."}

Comment: Thanks for the C# example. I've implemented the same using PowerShell, see the result here: https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2018/07/26/removing-the-password-protection-from-an-excel-sheet-using-powershell/

Comment: When you create a password protected document in the Office User Interface you will find that it becomes a Microsoft Compound File Binary File Format (MS-CFB) document (not a ZIP package), though the file extension does not change (e.g., xlsx, docx, pptx).  Subsequently, the UI protected document will open within the Office UI but you
cannot rename the file extension to *.zip and browse it with Explorer. (...) At this point in time the Open XML SDK does not provide functionality to open or create files with Compound File protection (CFB document)