# macos/.NET - How to create a NETv4 applications

Tags: .net

I'm trying to open a .xlsx with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, but when I create a project, Visual Studio don't let me pick the NET version to use.
It uses v2, and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel uses v4.6.1

I have downloaded NET Core and installed, but nothing changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Prueba.Controllers{
    [Route("/api/[controller]")]
    public class OtroController : Controller{
        [HttpGet]
        public void SS(){
            var ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
            ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("/Applications/protected.xls",ReadOnly: true, Password: "1234");

        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
```

NuGet Outputs:

```
Package 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.4795.1000' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Comment: First you need to understand the difference between https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server .NET Core and .NET Framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Interop` libraries will only work on Windows as that is for COM. macOS does not have COM.

A few notes:

- The .NET Framework does not run on Mac.
- .NET Core != .NET Framework
- There is the OpenXML SDK that you can use to modify Office document files.

Comment: Okay, but can I read password protected files with OpenXML SDK?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642952/how-to-unprotect-sheet-using-openxml-code

Comment: I have installed OpenXML by NuGet, but I'm getting troubles with file locations, how should I give the file location in macos?  "/Applications/file.xlsx" ? "\\Aplications\\file.xlsx"? Those don't work. :(

Comment: Or should I have the file on project folder..?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz that's a separate problem.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz i would ask a new question.